# Error: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.sam.simple.Project

Tags: android, firebase, exception, firebase-realtime-database, logcat

I was trying to store user information, for instance a NAME. But I got into some error. Searched and applied methods, but I got errors, logCat is posted below. Can I get a workaround please?

I want to add a new root called "USERS" and user info under that, like a user profile.

But now I just want to add Name of the user.

Below are some codes...

"MY CODE"

```
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });


    btn_save_edit_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user_name_string = user_name_edit.getText().toString();

            if (!user_name_string.equals("")){
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String userID = user.getUid();

                databaseReference.child(userID).child("Name").setValue(user_name_string);
                Toast.makeText(ProfileEditActivity.this, "Saved Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        }
    });
```

LOGCAT

```
Process: com.sam.simple, PID: 23912

                                       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.sam.simple.Project
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.adw.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.adw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.sam.simple.FirebaseHelper.fetchData(FirebaseHelper.java:52)
                                                                                    at com.sam.simple.FirebaseHelper.access$000(FirebaseHelper.java:14)
                                                                                    at com.sam.simple.FirebaseHelper$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseHelper.java:65)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.uv.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.aaf.zzIo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.aal.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

OUTPUT WANTED

[image]

NOTE: IS IT BECAUSE MY "Project" root is causing any problem? Database maybe pointing towards main root and things? I am new to this. any help? thanks

UPDATE #1: Added My Next Datasnapshot for Projects if this can help any further?

```
DatabaseReference db;
Boolean saved = null;
ArrayList<Project> projects=new ArrayList<>();

public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
    this.db = db;
}

//WRITE IF NOT NULL
public Boolean save(Project project)
{
    if(project==null)
    {
        saved=false;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            db.child("Project").push().setValue(project);
            saved=true;

        }catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved=false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}

//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    projects.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Project project = ds.getValue(Project.class);
       projects.add(project);
    }
}

//READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST
public ArrayList<Project> retrieve() {

    /*Query queryreference = db.orderByChild("postedDate");*/
    /*Query lastToFirstQuery = db.orderByChild("postedDate");*/

    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    return projects;
```

Comment: it's not there you error, you are trying to use `getValue(Project.class)` some where and that gives you the error

Comment: @OussemaAroua, i just added the "project class" at Update #1, can you help me with it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. **Even if there is only a single result**, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution above but this affected the "Project" and now it returns just blank. 
Though "Users" module works without any errors now. Is there any solution for this? please?

Comment: The code above is just reading data and not writting. So it could not affect you database in any way. Can you verify if the database looks like in the image that you have posted? Otherwise should work.

Comment: umm... it looks like the same (tbh, thats estimated output) but i think "project" node and "users" node are conflicting with each other.

Comment: Cannot be in conflic because both are diffrent nodes. Have you tried the code above? What is the error?

Comment: Hello there, I tried the above code, "Users" works well, i can add NAME. It creates the node and their child but when i get back to the DASHBOARD, for "Project" recyclerview, the data are either gone or same data is repeated 4 times. tried changing time and again but I get same kind of errors one or the another. EDIT: oh sometimes it also create "Project/Project/child" instead of "Project/child"... So thought user node is conflicting with the Project node.

Comment: The initial question was about `That error: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.sam.simple.Project`. Now i can say that i'm happy to hear that it worked well. The problem is not related with the initial one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Plase create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for it.

Comment: oh yes, i totally forgot, will close this topic now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment as a relatively new user but I've recently gotten the same issue also. 
Try changing this line `databaseReference.child(userID).child("Name").setValue(user_name_string);` to `databaseReference.child("Users").child(userID).child("Name").setValue(user_name_string);`

Your database reference is referencing the entire database, so adding `.child("Users")` narrows it down to the specific node you want to add to.
Also ensure your, User class matches your Firebase nodes perfectly.

Comment: Sorry but I got the same error even after adding [ .child("Users") ] @bruh1234